# I hard bricked my phone, now what?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, unbricking

So today I hard bricked my week old Iocean X8, as soon as my phone arrived it came stock with a jellybean ROM so I flashed it to the KitKat ROM provided by Iocean which all worked fine but I decided I wanted root access so then I attempted to flash to the super user ROM and that's when everything went downhill.

As far as my knowledge goes a hard brick is were the phone will not turn on and the PC will not recognize the phone. I also do not believe Iocean X8's come with a recovery mode.

I have sent an email to Iocean asking for the next steps to take but they are taking a little while to reply.

Have the Android Enthusiasts got any suggestions?

Comment: What does the phone do? Hard bricking usually happens when you flash a bad bootloader. If you can get to fastboot or recovery on the phone you are only "soft-bricked".

Answer (score 1):

Can you turn on your phone using special sequence of buttons  like power + middle button + down volume ? I don't know what is for your device but you can google tjat quickly...see if you can turn on in download or recovery mode. If yes try a factory reset and wipe cache data and reboot.

If that not work then is time to flash your stock firmware again on it you need odin and the stock firmware image you can search on xda developers forum for your device both the stock firmware and the guide on how to execute.If you not find on xda developers forum then try google but be careful don't download the first thing you see try to get the firmware atleast from a trusted source.

Your phone is not hard bricked it is soft bricked you bricked the software not the hardware but stay calm the above steps if done right should make your phone reboot again.

You will lose all your data if you want do to a backup you can try an backup via ADB you can google for "backup via adb android" follow all the steps with calm and carefully and you can make your phone reboot again without lose nothing.

Answer (score -2):

You could try install a RUU rom,bring the device back to stock,as explained by @freedom ,RUU is the stock rom, you must search for your device and xda dev should have working,trustable links for ruu rom/stock. then simply dont try gain root, if there is a reason for root, sure, but  really you had a rom custom in there,you really didnt need root. 
How to get there?
try hold power button+vol down , this should allow you to enter usb mode, try until you get there,because you must use recovery mode to fix problem completely, hence it is classed as a soft brick. Goodluck.